# How can I modify the following code to have the same results with "exists"?(SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, exists

I have been trying for hours but I can't think of anything as exists only returns boolean and every time I am trying to use exists I either get back the entire list of results or none.

This is the following code that returns me the result I want.

```
 SELECT  DISTINCT Clients.Clients_Code

 FROM         Account 

 INNER JOIN Clients ON Account.Account_Number = Clients.Account_Number 
 INNER JOIN Credit_Card ON Account.Account_Number = Credit_Card.Account_Number 
 INNER JOIN Transactions ON Credit_Card.Credit_Number = Transactions.Credit_Number 
 INNER JOIN Transactions AS Transactions_1 ON Credit_Card.Credit_Number = Transactions_1.Credit_Number 
 INNER JOIN Transactions AS Transactions_2 ON Credit_Card.Credit_Number = Transactions_2.Credit_Number 
 INNER JOIN Transactions AS Transactions_3 ON Credit_Card.Credit_Number = Transactions_3.Credit_Number

 WHERE (Transactions_3.Store_Code = '7182') 
 AND   (Transactions_2.Store_Code = '2019') 
 AND   (Transactions_1.Store_Code = '3121')
```

**THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR RESPONSE AND ESPECIALLY BENJAMIN. HIS RESPONSE WORKED PERFECTLY**

Comment: It'd be easier if you formatted your query more readably.  I think there's a pattern in the joins but I can't see it.

Comment: yup, agreed. too many joins going on here. should prob be a view.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve as this will make it easier to see how to rewrite your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've figured out from your details, you're trying to find a client that has used the same credit card at three different stores.  The following query would provide the same results.

```
SELECT Clients.Clients_Code
FROM Clients c
INNER JOIN Credit_Card cc ON cc.Account_Number = c.Account_Number
Where Exists(select * from Tranctions t with (nolock) where t.Store_Code = '7182' and t.Credit_Number = cc.Credit_Number) 
AND Exists(select * from Tranctions t with (nolock) where t.Store_Code = '2019' and t.Credit_Number = cc.Credit_Number) 
AND Exists(select * from Tranctions t with (nolock) where t.Store_Code = '3121' and t.Credit_Number = cc.Credit_Number)
```

An alternative is:

```
SELECT Clients.Clients_Code
FROM Clients c
INNER JOIN Credit_Card cc ON cc.Account_Number = c.Account_Number
Where (select count(*) from Tranctions t with (nolock) where t.Store_Code in ('7182', '2019','3121') and t.Credit_Number = cc.Credit_Number) =3
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you even need the Account table.

Does this work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Clients.Clients_Code FROM Clients 
INNER JOIN Credit_Card on Clients.Account_Number = Credit_Card.Account_Number 
WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT null FROM Transactions 
    WHERE Transactions.Credit_Number = Credit_Card.Credit_Number
    AND Transactions.Store_Code in ('7182','2019','3121')
)
```

Comment: This would return more results than the original query, since it would return the client code for any client that used the credit card at any of the three stores.  The original query selects clients that have used the same card at all three stores.

Comment: You're right - kind of missed that in an overzealous mood to simplify!

Comment: Yeah, I did the same thing the first time I looked at it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely. Are you asking how that query can return a boolean value rather than the actual records? If so:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT Clients.Clients_Code
            FROM Account 
            INNER JOIN Clients 
              ON Account.Account_Number = Clients.Account_Number 
            INNER JOIN Credit_Card 
              ON Account.Account_Number = Credit_Card.Account_Number 
            INNER JOIN Transactions 
              ON Credit_Card.Credit_Number = Transactions.Credit_Number 
            INNER JOIN Transactions AS Transactions_1 
              ON Credit_Card.Credit_Number = Transactions_1.Credit_Number 
            INNER JOIN Transactions AS Transactions_2 
              ON Credit_Card.Credit_Number = Transactions_2.Credit_Number 
            INNER JOIN Transactions AS Transactions_3 
              ON Credit_Card.Credit_Number = Transactions_3.Credit_Number
            WHERE (Transactions_3.Store_Code = '7182') 
              AND (Transactions_2.Store_Code = '2019') 
              AND (Transactions_1.Store_Code = '3121'))
   SELECT 1 --True
ELSE
   SELECT 0 --False
```

If that's not what you are trying to accomplish can you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is... odd.

I think you can achieve the same results with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Clients_Code
FROM Account AS a
INNER JOIN Clients AS c
    ON a.Account_Number = c.Account_Number
INNER JOIN Credit_Card AS cc
    ON a.Account_Number = cc.Account_Number
INNER JOIN Transactions AS t
    ON cc.Credit_Number = t0.Credit_Number
WHERE t.Store_Code IN ('7182', '2019', '3121')
```

If you want to know if any results exist for that query, then you want to just wrap the whole thing in an EXISTS([above_query]).